# Search query for multiple column with comma separated string

Tags: search, categories

$category_string="244,46,45";

**I want query that will return product id only 239.**

when i am trying to search by select * from category where category in($category_string) then it will give me all rows.

```
<table>
<tr><td>category_id</td><td>product_id</td></tr>
<tr><td>244</td><td>239</td></tr>
<tr><td>46</td><td>239</td></tr>
<tr><td>45</td><td>239</td></tr>
<tr><td>45</td><td>240</td></tr>
<tr><td>46</td><td>240</td></tr>
<tr><td>45</td><td>241</td></tr>
<tr><td>46</td><td>241</td></tr>
<tr><td>45</td><td>242</td></tr>
<tr><td>46</td><td>242</td></tr>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: `WHERE category_string = '239'` ?

Comment: do you means to get productid's only you can use select productid from category where .........

Comment: Please check, i have updated details with table.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want only 239**

`SELECT * FROM category WHERE product_id IN ( 239 );`

**OR**

`SELECT * FROM category WHERE product_id = 239;`

Since you are comparing for only one product_id, i would suggest 2 query.